# Is paper-toggle-button compliant with Material Design?

Tags: polymer, material-design, toggle, polymer-2.x, paper-elements

[On this page](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/settings.html#settings-usage), Material Design seems to specify toggle switch buttons should be placed on the right side of their label.

[image]

[image]

[But on the `<paper-toggle-button>` page of WebComponents.org](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button/elements/paper-toggle-button), the only available option appears to place the toggle switch button on the left side of the label.

[image]

And none of the styling options seem to address this issue.

Is this a fundamental incompatibility with MD or am I missing something? In any event, what is the recommended best practice to comply with the MD spec?

Edit:

[Here is an open issue on Github.](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button/issues/99)

[And here is an open PR.](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button/pull/111)

So apparently a fix is in progress. I just need to know what is "best practice" in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *Materialize* `<paper-toggle-button>`, do not use the installed label feature. Instead, create a separate label that can be independently positioned and styled.

```
<div class="start">
  Auto-rotate screen
</div>
<div class="end">
  <paper-toggle-button checked="{{autoRotateScreen}}"></paper-toggle-button>
</div>
```